# how to clear all data while uninstalling the app

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Am developing React native expo bare flow app, Actually am using expo secure store to store the user Auth Token for checking login status, and while Logout I just cleared expo secure store. But if the user uninstalled the app without logout and reinstalling the App then the app is redirected to the main screen Because the expo secure store still maintains the Auth token. How to clear expo secure store data while uninstalling.

Am facing this Issue with IOS, Please give any suggestions to fix this.

Comment: I don't really see the problem... Why do you wan't the user to be logged out when he uninstalls the app

Comment: we are using two endpoints one for production and one for stagging if stagging user login with the app if he uninstalls and reinstalls the app with production end point means the app allows users to log but stagging users' details are not present in production in and keep loading.

Comment: @MaximilianDietel Personally, I want the behavior of my app to by identical between ios and android devices. My issue is if it stays logged in for ios, but not for android between uninstall/re-install, this behavior is caught by qa and a bug is filed.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue in the native iOS world. Keychain (secure store) holds references to previous install of an app.

For me solution was to have a flag in UserDefaults (that is cleared between uninstalls) that indicated some data - i.e. first launch date.
If the flag was empty, we knew that app was freshly launched and I should clean the shared keychain before running the app for the first time.

Comment: would be nice if you could provide an example on how you used expo this way.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative solution is to store your secrets under a random key that is stored in non-secure storage (which is wiped at uninstall).
It will still be there after reinstallation, but it can't be accessed.

Someone else's idea: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/36442?answerId=112814022#112814022